# OAuth 2.0 Authentication Flow with Paw and Funky Redirect URI

Tags: oauth-2.0, paw-app

The API I'm using requires that my OAuth 2.0 redirect URI be `urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob`. So when I initiate the authentication flow in Paw, I am presented with this:

[image]

Where do I paste that code into Paw? Or is there a more automatic way I should be authenticating?

Comment: Sorry for the late follow up, I've just left a new answer.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're using an OAuth 2 "Authorization Code" flow, in which case the code needs to be then sent back to the server in order to get an authentication token.

Unfortunately, as your API doesn't provide the code automatically through a URL query param, Paw isn't able to retrieve the code and continue the normal flow. I'm afraid that in your case you won't be able to use Paw's automated OAuth 2 flow.

Instead, you may setup manually multiple requests in Paw:

- One request to query this page (the Authorization URL)
- One request to get access token using the `code` you've got (the Access Token URL)